# How can I access Azure Blobs by URL with Active Directory custom javascript file?

Tags: jquery, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom Azure AD signup page and I have included privacy policy and terms and condition links. so when I click both links I should be able to navigate custom privacy policy and TnC pages.

```
$('#lableTnC').html("I agree to the <a id='tnc' href='javascript:void(0)'>Terms and Conditions</a> of use");
```

How can I include Blob_url/termsAndContion.html for the above link?

I have Used Blob URL in HTML like this. Its working perfectly

```
<img src="#{BLOB_URL}#/assets/img/sample.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable static websites and move the file to a folder $web for it to work with HTML files. This will ensure the page is served as a web page rather than a file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website